# nginx does not serve to non-www domain

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx configuration, which is supposed to serve the index.html file to both [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and domain.com. While [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) works, domain.com returns the default nginx welcome page.
What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
listen              80;
listen              [::]:80;
server_name         domain.com www.domain.com;
root /home/ubuntu/coming-soon-page/frontend/react_ui/build;

location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off; log_not_found off;
}

error_page 403 /home/ubuntu/coming-soon-page/frontend/react_ui/build/index.html;

location / {
    root /home/ubuntu/coming-soon-page/frontend/react_ui/build/;
    index index.html;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location = /submit_user_feedback {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/coming-soon-page/backend/api/api.sock;
}
```

}

Comment: Check the `server_name` directive. Make sure there are no typos and only spaces are used to separate the parameters. Use `curl -I` to test the website.

Comment: Turns out the change needed some time to show up. For whatever reason. All solved now!